# Positioning JLabel in JPanel below the image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I want to move the Text below the image and shape in the given example. 
Please help me to do it.

```
    package test;

    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;        
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;        
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class TestLabel extends JPanel {

        private Integer size = 70;
        private String name;
        private Image image;

        public TestLabel(Integer size, String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.size = size;
            setSize(size, size + size / 4);
            this.image = new ImageIcon(new Node().getClass().getResource("/com/businesslense/topology/images/node1.jpg")).getImage();
            JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(name);
            textLabel.setBounds(100,100,70,30);
            add(textLabel);
            setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51), 2));
        }



        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

            int imagePaddingVal = (int) ((Math.sqrt(2) * (((size * 115) / 100) / 2))) / 4;
            int imageSize = (size * 85) / 100;
            int imageRadius = (int) (Math.sqrt(2) * (imageSize / 2));

            g2d.drawImage(image, imagePaddingVal, imagePaddingVal, imageRadius, imageRadius, this);

            int shapePaddingVal = (size * 5) / 100;
            int shapeRadius = (size * 90) / 100;

            g2d.drawOval(shapePaddingVal, shapePaddingVal, shapeRadius, shapeRadius);

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));


        }

        public static void main(String argv[]){
            TestLabel tl = new TestLabel(70,"Test");
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();

            jf.add(tl);

            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setSize(300, 400);
        }
    }
```

In this example, JLable comes in the top of the panel. I want to move it down to the image/shape.

I tried with `setBounds()` but that didnt work. Please tell me if i am missing something.

Comment: Beware that failing to call `super.paintComponent` will generated unwated paint artifacts

Comment: Just use `g.drawString`. Forget the label. fyi, the reason your setBounds doesn't work is because it only works with null layouts. JPanel has a default FlowLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider making use of the API's available functionality...

Take a look at:

- [`JLabel#setHorizontalTextPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalTextPosition%28int%29)
- [`JLabel#setVerticalTextPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalTextPosition%28int%29)
- [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

For example...

```
private ImageIcon image;

public TestLabel100(Integer size, String name) {
    //...
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(name);
    textLabel.setIcon(image);
    textLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    textLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.SOUTH);        
    //textLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 70, 30);
    //...
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //...
```